# PHP: Accessing two dimensional array from a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, 2d, multidimensional-array

Hello I can not figure out how to access a two dimensional array returned by a function.

My function `query($query)` inside a *Connection* class(inside `Connection.php`):

```
public function query($query)
  {
      $result = mysql_query($query);

       $array= array();
      for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
      {
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
       for($j=0;$j<(sizeof($row)/2);$j++)
       {
         $array[i][j]=$row[$j];
       }
      }
      return $array;
    }
```

and My test.php file:

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';

$obj1 = new Connection();
echo $obj1->toString();

$array=$obj1->query("SELECT * FROM LeCars ORDER BY ID;");
echo $array[0][0];
echo 'asd:',$array[0][0],'<br>';
echo 'asd:',$array[0][1],'<br>';
echo 'asd:',$array[0][2],'<br>';
echo 'asd:',$array[1][0],'<br>';
echo 'asd:',$array[2][4],'<br>';
var_export($array);
```

?>

output of test.php:

ip : 194.00.00.27
login: asd123
password: asd123
table: asdasd1123
query: asd:
asd:
asd:
asd:
asd:
array ( 'i' => array ( 'j' => NULL, ), )

Any1 knows how to send that array into test.php properly ?

What I tried: looping it, sending by refference, double checked if array rly works(it does), but I cant send it to test and access it there

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() does not return 2-dimensional array. It return 'resource' which means it is noa t a php type object. You can operate on it with special function.

See docs and examples right here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: values are being put into the 2d array - that part is working. Now I want to send the array and use it in test.php.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, toString() should only return that string value, not print it.

Then, two-diumensional arrays returned from function are just like normal two-dimensional arrays - haven't you tried:

```
$array=$obj1->query("SELECT * FROM LeCars ORDER BY ID;");
echo $array[0][0];
```

?

Also please consider reading the PHP manual for "foreach" and "count".